# How to change post title place in JavaScript blog widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget, blogger

I added custom java script latest post widget to my blog site.So it show post title next to the post image.(part A - please see image)
But I want to put post title under the post image (like Part B.-please see image.I tried so many times,but goes wrong.
please help me to correct this ?

Here is the full code :
https://textuploader.com/1du1w

image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxA43.gif
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd5TQ.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is replace this part of the script:

```
<td><a href="'+posturl+'" ><img src="'+img[i]+'" width="'+thumbwidth+'" height="'+thumbheight+'"/></a></td><td>'+icon+'<a href="'+posturl+'" >'+posttitle+'</a></td>
```

width this:

```
<td><a href="'+posturl+'" ><img src="'+img[i]+'" width="'+thumbwidth+'" height="'+thumbheight+'"/><span class="title"> '+icon+' '+posttitle+'</span></a></td>
```

That puts all elements (image AND title) into one table td, and also adds a span class to the title so that we can style with a little css:

> <style>
> table {
>   border: 1px solid;
> }
> table a img {
>   object-fit: cover;
>   width: 100%;
> }
> .title {
>   display: block;
>   text-align: center;
> }
> <style>

In the css above, I gave a border to the table element just for test purposes and made the image fit the width of the table.

Is this something close to what you're looking?